# Is there a better way of creating elements and appending text to/around them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a bunch of lines that look like:

```
txt = "Can't print the value for <span class='keyword'>"+arguments[1]+"</span> before it's set";
```

I'm then doing

```
$('#mydiv').append($('<div/>').html(txt));
```

This looks terrible and I need to escape any html inside arguments[1]

The only alternative I can think of is to make sure all the text is inside its own element:

```
var spans = [];
spans[0] = $('<span/>').text("Can't print the value for ");
spans[1] = $('<span/>').text(arguments[1]).className('keyword');
spans[2] = $('<span/>').text(" before it's set");
$('#mydiv').append($('<div/>').append(spans[0],spans[1],spans[2]));
```

This is quite a lot for just a simple line of text. Is there anything else I can do?

edit: This isn't something that should be handled by a templating engine. It's html generated by a javascript logging function.

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL, Even assuming codereview isn't as dead as it currently is, I still feel this belongs more here. It is a specific problem with a specific solution (that seems to allude me).

Comment: you can consider a templating solution http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: @3nigma, It seems like they're dropping the idea.

Comment: @Walkerneo yup jquery has dropped "official" support for the templates but they are going to be developed, so the idea is not dropped, there are other templating solutions available

Comment: here is a demo if you are interested http://jsfiddle.net/U2kNG/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It's a consistent format, I'd add it as a normal string and then do a search for the keyword part.

```
$('<div/>')
  .appendTo('#mydiv')
  .html("Can't print the value for <span class='keyword'></span> before it's set")
  .find('.keyword').text(arguments[1]);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. I think the advantage here is you don't need a templating library. This is great for small sentences where certain parts need to be replaced. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you will be continuing to create lots of HTML using JS, I would suggest working with a templating library. I am a recent convert, it took me a long time to understand the point. But seeing many successful sites (twitter,github,etc.) and the great John Resig [promote](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and/or make heavy use of templating, i'm glad I stuck with trying to understand. Now I get it. It's for separation of concerns, keeping logic out of the view.

I'm using this very bare bones templating library: http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/ though the templating provided by [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) are more popular.

The advantage of the library i'm using is its really small, <1kb and is basically like writing php/asp code if you are familiar with those.

you can write HTML inside `<script>` tags without having to escape:

using your variable, `txt`, the syntax looks like this:

```
<script>
  var data={txt : "Can't print the value for <span class='keyword'>"+arguments[1]+"</span> before it's set"};

  <div>{%=o.txt%}</div>
</script>
```